# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I get this error: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"`. I can't find the fault in my code. I don't use CSS now, nor jQuery.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!--<script src="js/banner_test_script.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ban"></div>
        <script src="js/banner_test_script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function what()
{
    var myTimery = setInterval(function() {
        myTimer();
    }, 1000);

    var imgn = 0;
    function myTimer()
    {
        if (imgn === 0)
        {
            var d = "../../download.jpg";
            imgn++;
        }
        else if (imgn === 1)
        {
            var d = "../../images.jpg";
            imgn++;
        }
        else if (imgn === 2)
        {
            var d = "../../images1.jpg";
            resetImgn();
        }
        var p = '<img src="' + d + '"></img>';
        document.getElementById("ban").innerHTML = "lol";
        document.writeln(p);
        console.log(document.getElementById('ban') + "1");
        console.log(document.getElementById("ban") + "2");
    }
    ;

    function resetImgn()
    {
        imgn = 0;
    }
    ;
    /*
     function myTimer()
     {
     for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
     {
     document.writeln(i);
     }
     }
     ;
     */
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `document.write` (or `document.writeln`) after the initial parsing of the page (which you do, because you're using it in a timer), that implicitly does a `document.open`, which wipes out the existing page entirely (and the replaces it with what you write). So your elements no longer exist when you try to look them up.

It's not clear to me what your `document.writeln(p)` is meant to do, but if you remove it, you'll stop wiping out your element, and `document.getElementById` should be able to find it.

If your goal is to have the image markup in `p` written to the `ban` element, then:

```
document.getElementById("bad").innerHTML = p;
```

...and removing `document.writeln` will do it.

---

Side note: That `setInterval` line can be just: `var myTimery = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);` Functions are first-class objects.

---

Side note 2: You seem to be cycling between `imgn` 0, 1, 2, then back to 0. You have somewhat complicated logic for doing it. Just FYI, there's a handy trick using the `%` operator you can use:

```
imgn = (imgn + 1) % 3;
```

Assuming you start with 0, the next will be 1, then 2, then 0, then 1...

Comment: +1. Also, if the OP is trying to dynamically add the image tag to the document he can use `appendChild`. For example `var p = document.createElement('img'); p.setAttribute('src', d); document.body.appendChild(p);`